# PHP: calling an API protected using basic authentication

Tags: php, authentication, curl

I have an API deployed on a server that's now protected using basic authentication.

I also have a script running on the SAME server that the APi running on, that needs to call the API.

script: test.php

```
<?php
$url = 'https://my_site.myapi/account/add/{"account_id":"1234555"}
$username = 'myname';
$password = 'mypassword';
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.":".$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I try calling test.php from a browser:

```
https://my_site.myapi/test.php
```

I am promoted for user name and password. I am not getting an error message. Any ideas?

## VirtualHost Section

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite/web/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/api_section_1">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
</Directory>

Alias /winapi /var/www/another_section/
<Directory "/var/www/another_section">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Access"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting prompted for a password, that's not coming from your curl call, but rather apache. My guess is that your https://my_site.myapi/test.php page is also mistakenly protected by the basic auth.

curl_exec() would return an error indicating that authentication was required, not prompt you for it.

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper I assume you've restarted Apache after making these changes? Does it prompt for credentials for other scripts in that same directory?

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache. I deleted the passwords files and re-created it. That solved the problem.

Comment: But, I also initially had the main document directory protected (that's in addition to the corrupt passwords file)

Answer (score 0):

Is your basic authentication expecting any encoding - for example the username and password token may need to be base64 encoded.

Another thing to check is that the details make it into the Authorization header - check the request headers to see if this is the case.

Comment: I tried it with and without base64 encoding. I thought that the point of using cUrl is that I did not need to send an Authorization header

Comment: I would imagine that curl abstracts you from setting it, but sets it based on the curl options you pass. You need to check the actual request headers to see what is really sending.